# Remove default document from url without removing files ending in the default document name

Tags: regex, iis

I have this rule in my web.config:

```
<!-- Rule to remove "index.asp" -->
<rule name="Default document rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)index.asp" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

(I'll change "temporary" to "permanent" once this is locked in.)

With that `sitename.com/index.asp` becomes `sitename.com` and `sitename.com/dir/index.asp` becomes `sitename.com/dir/`. So far, so good.

But, when I go to `sitename.com/testindex.asp` it becomes `sitename.com/test` and blows up. It should stay as `sitename.com/testindex.asp`. How do I modify the rule for that? (Note: It must also preserve the query string.)

Comment: Either you learn more about regular expressions or use a modern AI to assist.

Comment: `(.*)/index.asp` perhaps?

Comment: You might also want to consider adding `$` to the end if you don't want to match something like `index.aspx`

Comment: @LexLi I tried a number of AI prompts before posting this question. Unfortunately, nothing did the trick. Definitely wouldn't hurt to learn more RE, but my need for it is so spread out, I usually forget what I've learned between uses. Was hoping to get some help here if it's an easy answer for someone who already has a strong RE knowledgebase.

Comment: @Nick good call. Will do.

Comment: @YurongDai No luck so far.

Comment: @NickPetrie did you try my suggestion with the added `/` in the regex?

Comment: @Nick oops sorry. Yes, I did. So that partially worked. `sitename.com/dir/index.asp` became `sitename.com/dir/` which is good. And `sitename.com/dir/testindex.asp` did not get redirected, which is also good. But `sitename.com/index.asp` was not redirected at all. Seems with the `/` it doesn't touch the root-level files.

Comment: I may have gotten it to work. Not sure what side effects this might produce, but I changed the regex to `^(.*)\bindex.asp$` using the word boundary `\b`. All of my test cases work so far.

Comment: That won't work for something like `dir/word-index.asp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
^(.+/)?index.asp$
```

This matches:

- `^` : beginning of string
- `(.+/)?` : optionally, some number of characters followed by a `/`
- `index.asp` : literally, `index.asp`
- `$` : end of string

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/96f06b/1)

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the following rewrite rule in web.config:

```
<rule name="efault document rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="index.asp" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: No luck. It just redirects infinitely.